# Is it possible to use sjplot::plot_model() to plot confidence interval along y-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, confidence-interval

I would like to plot vertical confidence interval graph instead of horizontal confidence intervals graph.

Something like this:

[image]

from [Statistics Globe Newsletter](https://statisticsglobe.com/draw-plot-with-confidence-intervals-in-r).

Comment: The way this was done was in the very link you shared. Which part was not working for you?

Comment: I just wonder if plot_model can plot this type of graph, since I read the help file and cannot find a argument relates to my requirement...

Comment: You would need to revise your question to specifically ask about how plot_model can be used for your use case.

Comment: So you are after an sjPlot::plot_model but rotated, as the pure ggplot charts you linked are?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, yes it is possible. Here is the data taken from the [vignette example](https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/blob/1ec67c779d8def9ba55847dc97a76304fd224124/R/plot_models.R).

```
# prepare data
library(sjmisc)
data(efc)
efc <- to_factor(efc, c161sex, e42dep, c172code)
m <- lm(neg_c_7 ~ pos_v_4 + c12hour + e42dep + c172code, data = efc)

# simple forest plot
plot_model(m)
```

To create rotated errorbars, you need to apply `coord_fixed` first as  `coord_flip` was already applied based on the [source code](https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/blob/1ec67c779d8def9ba55847dc97a76304fd224124/R/plot_models.R). Then you can rotate the x axis text to make them readable.

```
p+coord_fixed() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]

To have the bars appear on the whiskers, you may need to draw over the default error bars as the width have been hard-coded.

```
p+coord_fixed() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + 
  geom_errorbar(
    aes_string(ymin = "conf.low", ymax = "conf.high"),
    width = 0.25
  )
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to ask one more thing: is it possible to plot two coefficients into the same vertical line in plot_model?

Comment: What do you mean by two coefficients?  It may be possible, but your original question do not reflect this so you may need to edit your question.